# Salto de linea desde php

Tags: php

Hola les quiero pedir ayuda ya que quiero desde un archivo que no es **.txt** dar un salto de linea, creo que no me expliqué bien pero para entender aquí les dejo mi codigo:

```
    $fp = fopen($file, 'a+');
    fwrite($fp, "texto");
```

Como pueden ver solo estoy abriendo un archivo pero el archivo no es uno **.txt** mi pregunta es ¿como puedo hacer para que se inserte un salto de linea?, intente con `\r\n` y tambien solo con `\n` pero no puedo, agradezco su ayuda, gracias :).

Comment: Te da algún error? En la documentación de fopen te dice `Si no especifica la bandera 'b' cuando está trabajando con ficheros binarios, puede experimentar problemas extraños con su información, incluidos ficheros imagen rotos o problemas extraños con los caracteres \r\n.`. podría ser que te falta abrirlo con `b`?

Comment: Lo siento busque a lo que te refieres pero soy malo buscando entonces me puedes decir detalladamente a lo que te refieres, por favor

Comment: en https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fopen, te dice ese comentario de utilizar la bandera 'b'. Es decir, que revises tu instruccion     `$fp = fopen($file, 'a+');`y mira si necesitas abrirlo como     `$fp = fopen($file, 'ab+');`. Esto es porque comentas que abres un archivo que "no es de texto" (es decir, un binario). Es eso?

Comment: @Jakala convine lo que me dijiste con la respuesta que me escribieron y ya funciono, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu fichero no es .txt es buena idea decir que tipo es... pero de todos modos

Es mejor que uses la constante `PHP_EOL`, esto será tu salto de línea, aunque en realidad marca el final de una.

```
$fp = fopen($file, 'a+');
fwrite($fp, "texto que quiero escribir" . PHP_EOL);
fwrite($fp, "Esto vendría siendo otra línea" . PHP_EOL);
```

Comment: si funciono como me dijiste, gracias

Comment: Aun no respondes que tipo de archivo es, pero que bueno que hayas solucionado el tema